# Ghosting on Panel

Tags: 16.04, unity, themes, panel

I'm not sure is it called ghosting but the menu options from closed programs still exist as a shade on the top bar. An image describes it better. This is how it looks:
[image: screenshot]

As you can see I'm not hovering my cursor on the Panel and yet Chromium's menu options are still visible.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, GTK+ theme is Adapta-Nokto. The problem emerged after a "system update" (`apt-get upgrade`) I suppose, it wasn't like that initially when I installed the theme.

How do I solve this?